# Do all p.d.f. with same c.d.f have same expected value?

Tags: probability, expected-value, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $F$ be a c.d.f. over reals and $\{R_i\}$ be the set of all real random variables with c.d.f. $F$. Do all $R_i$ have the same expected value? i.e. is the following statement true?

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[R_i] = \mathbb{E}[R_j] \quad \forall i, j
\end{equation}

If yes, why? If not, could you show me a counter-example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and you do not need the distribution to be continuous or have a density. You can say

$$\mathbb E[R_i] = \int\limits_0^{\infty}(1- F(x))\, dx-\int\limits_{-\infty}^0 F(x)\, dx$$ if the two integrals are finite; if both are infinite then the expectation is not defined.

So the same cumulative distribution function gives the same expectation.